# Can I use http streaming with axlsx_rails to avoid timeout issue with large/time intensive query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

I'm using the [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) Ruby gem in Rails 4.2.5 to generate an Excel file to let users download their data.

I have this in my index.xlsx.axlsx template:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Transactions') do |sheet|

  sheet.add_row ["Date", "Vendor Name", "Account",
             "Transaction Category",
             "Amount Spent", "Description"]

  @transactions.find_each(batch_size: 100) do |transaction|
    sheet.add_row [transaction.transaction_date,
      transaction.vendor_name,
      transaction.account.account_name,
      transaction.transaction_category.name,
      transaction.amount,
      transaction.description]
  end
end
```

The page times out before returning an Excel file if there's enough data. Is there a way to use HTTP streaming to send results back as it's processing, rather than waiting until the entire transactions.find_each loop has completed?

I saw code [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/streaming-with-rails-4/) using response.stream.write:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
10.times {
  response.stream.write "This is a test message"
  sleep 1
}
response.stream.close
```

That approach looks promising, but I couldn't figure out how to integrate response.stream.write into an axlsx_rails template. Is there a way?

This is my first Stack Overflow question- apologies for any faux pas and thank you for any ideas you can offer.

Comment: Are you calling filename in the url or are you using a render block in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can stream, I don't think it will be any faster. The problem is Axlsx is not going to generate your spreadsheet until you are done building it. And axlsx_rails just wraps that process, so it won't help either. So there will be no partial spreadsheet to serve in bits, and the delay will be just as long.

You should bite the bullet and try [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) (which is very fast) or some other job scheduler. Then you can return the request immediately and generate the spreadsheet in the background. You will have to do some kind of monitoring or notification to get the generated report, or a ping back to another url using javascript that forwards to a new page when a flag is set on render complete. Your call there.

Having a job scheduler is also very convenient when you need to fire off an email in response to a request; the response can return immediately and not wait for the email to complete. Once you have a scheduler you will find more uses for it.

If you choose a job scheduler, axlsx_rails will let you [use your template to generate the attachment](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#mailers), or you can [create your own view context to generate the file](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#scripts). Or for a really bare bones way of rendering the template, [see this test](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/blob/master/spec/axlsx_builder_spec.rb#L24-L28).

Comment: Thanks, @Noel and @Jamie! I'll take a look at Sidekiq. Since I'm only using the very basic features of axlsx (basically, I'm just looking for a glorified csv where I don't have to escape commas and linefeeds, etc) I may try just building up the xml for an Excel doc in my own code so I could stream it out row by row.

Comment: Streaming csv sounds like a workable solution. There are some good tutorials like this one from Railscasts that might help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, Joe.

I asked in comment, but perhaps it's better to answer and explain.

The short answer, is yes, you can always stream if you can render (though with sometimes mixed performance results).

It does not, however, work if your referencing a file directly.  IE, `http://someurl.com/reports/mycustomreport.xlsx`

Streaming in rails just isn't built that way by default.  But not to worry, you "should" still be able to tackle your issue, providing the time you wish to save is rendering only.

In your controller (* note for future, when you're asking about rendering actions, it helps to provide your controller action code *) you should be able to do something similar to:

```
def report
  @transactions = current_user.transactions.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render xlsx: 'report', stream: true}
  end
end
```

Might help to do a sanity check on your loading.  In your log as part of the 200 response you should get something like:

**Completed 200 OK in 506ms (Views: 494.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)**

If the active record number is too high, or higher than the view number, this solution might not work for your query, and as suggested, this might need to be threaded or sent to a job.

Comment: Thank you, @trh! I am using respond_to in my controller code:  In this case, I think it's the ActiveRecord query that's taking all the time

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! My controller would timeout for ~15k rows, and the query would be really quick, but `axlsx` would took too long to create the file, and this did the trick